# Why does xmllint not work in aurelia app but works in plain js app

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia, xmllint

I have a SDK kit that I made. It has a dependency of [xmllint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmllint) which is a wrapper to some C language command line tool and it can work in browser. Now I want to test if it all works in a browser environment. In sdk I had to make custom types for the xmllint since it doesent have its own and im using typescript inside the SDK.

```
declare module "xmllint"{
var xmllint:any;
export default xmllint;
}
```

I started with very simple js app that runs on `webpack-dev-server`. There I imported my SDK. Created the class instance that uses xmllint and called verify to verify xml with xsd. Works fine.

But since its mostly not gona be used on a plain js, I tryed with bit more complex app. I installed `aurelia-cli` and created a project with it (au new and setup with `typescript` and `npm`) and run it on `webpack-dev-server`. Now I use my SDK the same way, but now I get error:

> TypeError: xmllint_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__default.a.validateXML is not a function

My guess is some sort of aurelia or webpack config that the aurelia-cli created is causing this error, but I cant seem to find which config. What is causing this error in aurelia and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem. Issue was that webpack.config was missing a module rule

```
module:{
rules:[
...,
    {test: path.resolve(__dirname, "node-modules/xmllint/xmllint.js"),use:["imports-loader?require=>null", "exports-loader?xmllint"]}
,...
}]}
```

Comment: Can you share a better example? How to use this snippet?

Comment: Thanks but don't work in vue cli...how to write this in vue.config.js syntax?

Comment: @gfdevelop im not familiar with vue so i cant help you there. But what i did is basicli import-export hack for webpack. xmllint.js is compiled from C source into JS so there are no normal export there. You need to find how does vue resolve paths.